# What does this headline mean? - "Fiji turns the page"

Tags: idioms, headlinese

> [**Fiji turns the page**](http://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/fiji-turns-the-page/article6432206.ece) (source: *The Hindu* online newspaper)

Does this mean that Fiji is progressing?  Turning the page means moving forward, no? I am trying to do speed reading and want to guess the headlines. Is my understanding right here?

Can I say that it is all about Fiji progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **turn the page** is a (modern, relatively uncommon) variant of the long-established idiomatic usage...

> [**To Turn Over a New Leaf**](http://idiomorigins.net/turn-over-a-new-leaf/)
>    *to make a fresh start, to change your behavior or attitude. In the 16th century people referred to pages in a book as “leaves”. When they turned over a new leaf it meant they were turning to a blank page in a workbook to start a new lesson. This could also be more generally used as to say you’re **turning over a page of your life** and starting a new one, etc.*

---

In fact, even *"Fiji turns over a new leaf"* would be unlikely phrasing for OP's exact context, because essentially it means [*start to act or behave in a better or more responsible way*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/turn-over-a-new-leaf). Thus it implies that previously, Fiji had been acting badly/immorally, which probably isn't the intent in OP's example.

The citation is from [an editorial in The Hindu](http://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/fiji-turns-the-page/article6432206.ece), so perhaps this usage is more "normal" in Indian English. But I'd expect *British* newspapers to use something more like...

> *"Fiji starts a new chapter"*
>    *"Fiji rewrites the book"*
>    *"Fiji breaks with tradition"*
>    *"Fiji breaks the mould"*
>    etc., etc.

...all of which strongly emphasise *the fact of starting something **completely new,*** with less of the (probably unwanted) implications of having abandoned previous undesirable patterns of behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, moving forward (improving) after not having done very well for quite a while. For example, a team that was on a losing streak and then wins two games in a row could be "turning the page".

EDIT:
http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/turn+the+page

Comment: I'm not too convinced by your example. The standard idiom there would be *turning the **corner*** when reversing/breaking a losing streak.

Comment: "This marks a new democratic beginning for the South Pacific nation *after suffering self-inflicted wounds over a period of some 28 years*." from The Hindu editorial you cited. Emphasis mine.

Comment: But I agree with you that "turning the corner" is the more common of the two idioms.

Comment: I tracked down the original context, but didn't bother to read the whole article. I see your point that those emphasised words do push us closer to the *abandon previous undesirable activity* implications of page/leaf turning, but I still think it's a slightly unusual usage here. The article is far more about ***adopting** a new **desirable** approach*, rather than ***abandoning** the previous **undesirable** behaviour*.

Comment: Well, the emphasis would depend on the eye of the beholder, and a newspaper headline does not always perfectly reflect the article. But there are other mentions of undesirable circumstances: "Bainimarama will be able to put behind him the phase of global condemnation and international sanctions that had followed the 2006 coup...long-simmering rivalries  ... corruption, racial divisions ... policies steeped in racial discrimination and dispossession ...hereditary, rival power bases...restrictive media framework involving stiff penalties for critical coverage...cloud of human rights abuses "

Comment: I guess. But I think for most learners the take-home message here should be that *turning the page* is non-standard to Anglophones at large, so it doesn't really matter too much what it "means". For all I know, it's common in IE, where it may have either, neither, or both the ***stop** doing **bad** things* and ***start** doing **new** (desirable, interesting) things*. For interest's sake it would be good if a native IE speaker could fill us in on that point, but it's probably not a usage the average learner should plan to incorporate into his own speech and writing.

Comment: I've added a citation to the Cambridge Idioms Dictionary. I don't know why you say the idiom is `non-standard to Anglophones at large`, when it is simply less often used than "turn the corner" or "turn over a new leaf". The latter is more popular by far, but "turn the page" is making inroads because fewer and fewer people know that a "leaf" is a page, indeed fewer and fewer know any terminology at all relating to books and manuscripts.

Comment: I (erroneously, I now realise after looking at [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+turned+the+page%2Chas+turned+the+corner&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chas%20turned%20the%20page%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chas%20turned%20the%20corner%3B%2Cc0)) said "turn the page" was a *modern* variant in my answer. Perhaps "non-standard" was putting it a bit strong. But this is a *learners* site, so given how much less common it is than several less "transparent" usages, it's hardly worth "learning to use" -mere *recognition* suffices.